# Convert textbox type to password in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do I convert a textbox type to password in asp.net mvc?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You mean `<%=Html.Password("test")%>`?

Comment: i want my textbox to show *** when i write in password field instead of plain text

Comment: so yes, you should use the code above. Or, <input type="password" name="mypass">

Comment: I am guessing the guy is using razer views in asp.net mvc.

Comment: Note this hasn't been valid syntax since MVC 1, we're now on MVC 5(+) and you should be using [Razor syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16535920/542251)

Answer (score 70):

Just write in Razor View i.e. in .cshtml file below line

```
  @Html.PasswordFor(m=>m.Password)
```

Here m is model object and password is the password field name.

Answer (score 14):

Either use the HTML helper function `Password`:

```
<%= Html.Password("Password") %>
```

or use the `type` parameter on an input field:

```
<input name="password" type="password" />
```

See listings 4 and 5 on [this page](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/asp-net-mvc-views-overview-cs)

Answer (score 5):

There are many types of using password-typed textboxes in ASP. NET MVC

With html controls it would be like;

```
<input type="password" name="xx" id="yy">
```

With Razor-syntax it would be like;

```
@Html.Password(name, value, html_attributes)
```

Or in a strongly typed view you could write

```
@Html.PasswordFor(model=>model.Password)
```

Answer (score 3):

When using a strong-typed view and bootstrap, use the following code to make sure the password field is properly styled:

```
@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 2):

below is extention based on html helper:

before converting:

```
@Html.TextBox("mypass", null, new { style = "width: 200px;" })
```

After converting:

```
@Html.Password("mypass", null, new { style = "width:200px;" })
```

hope helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Password" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In .cshtml file:

```
@Html.PasswordFor(modal => modal.Password)
```

Comment: why not add some explanation? it is always good practice to add explanations to answers as it helps the OP and others understand what you are attempting

Comment: This is just re-iterating what everyone else has already said, multiple times. Please don't do this

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to add `@type = password` to your `html.texbox()` attributes like so:

before converting:

```
@Html.TextBox("mypass", null, new { @class = "" })
```

After converting:

```
@Html.TextBox("mypass", null, new { @class = "", @type = password })
```

This will mask your text box text with circles instead of text. It does this, because the `@type = password` attribute tells your text box that it is of type "password".

This method of converting your text box to type password is an easy quick way to to make the conversion from your standard razor form text box.

Comment: The best answer I found here. This doesn't screw up the design too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, 
      "Password",
       new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Comment: There is no context/explanation to your line of code. Please add some explanation as well.

Answer (score 0):

Convert textbox type to password in asp.net mvc

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Password", @type="Password" } })
```