# Update hidden field value on every keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a `MVC` form, with `Name`, `Email`, `ConfirmEmail` fields.
As I start typing in the ConfirmEmail field, the Email field should be masked by *.
The form should only be posted when the `Email` and `ConfirmEmail` fields match.

I started with the `Compare` data annotation attribute in MVC, but when I wrote the `keypress` function to mask the `Email` field to `*`, the `Compare` attribute started to throw error, because the value of the Email field gets changed.

Then I wrote `jQuery` code to achieve it, I have a `hidden field` in which I keep the original `Email` value and I am trying to update the hidden field value whenever the Email field changes. This hidden field doesn't get updated properly and the validation fails. Please help.

Below is my code:

MVC Form:

```
<form>
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
<span id="spanFirstName" class="alert-danger"></span>

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control"})
<span id="spanEmail" class="alert-danger"></span

 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ConfirmEmail, new { @class = "form-control"})
<span id="spanConfirmEmail" class="alert-danger"></span>
<input type="submit" data-attr="SendEmail" class="btn btn-primary" value="Post" />
</form>
```

jQuery Code:

```
         $(document)
            .on("keypress", "#Email", function (e) {
                if ($('#Email').val().indexOf('*') !== -1) {
                    $('#hiddenEmail').val($('#hiddenEmail').val());
                }
                else {
                    $('#hiddenEmail').val($('#Email').val());
                }
            });

        $(document)
            .on("keypress", "#ConfirmEmail", function (e) {
                if ($('#Email').val() !== null || $('#Email').val() !== '') 
                {
                   $('#Email').val($('#Email').val().replace(/[^\s]/g,"*"));
                }
            });

        $(document)
            .off("click", "[data-attr='SendEmail']")
            .on("click", "[data-attr='SendEmail']", function (e) {
                validate();
            });

function validate() {
        var firstName = $('#Name').val();
        var email = $('#Email').val();
        var confirmEmail = $('#ConfirmEmail').val();
        var hiddenEmail = $('#hiddenEmail').val();
        if (hiddenEmail !== "" && confirm !== "") {
            if (hiddenEmail !== confirmEmail) {
                $('#spanConfirmEmail').text('Email Addresses do not match');
            }
            else {
                $('#spanConfirmEmail').text('');
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Setting your textfield type as password should help. Check the ref here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897160/convert-textbox-type-to-password-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: What is the point of 'masking' a confirm email address? And it makes even less since the original email is not masked. If you really want to mask them, use an input with `type="password"`

Comment: If you truly need to obfuscate the confirm email field in this way, why don't you just use type="password"? You shouldn't need an additional, hidden field for this.

Comment: I have few more fields such as radio buttons as well in the form. If I use @Html.PasswordFor, the Email field gets prepopulated with the logged in user's id.

Comment: Also, in the console I get an error and a link to https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/create-amazing-password-forms

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Can a popup be opened on input type=submit button click in ASP.NET MVC??

Comment: Yes - using javascript (but not sure what that has to do with your question)

Comment: Please show the error message in console log. A popup can be opened from submit button by using `preventDefault()` to override normal submit action and show it afterwards (depending on library you're using).